# Inaccurate Form size

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create a form with a 500 x 500 form size.

Then I create a panel with a 500 x 500 size.

Logically, the panel size would be the same as the form size.

However, the panel turns out to be significantly larger than the form.

This gave me the conclusion that the form size turns much smaller than the given size which is 500 x 500.

How do I make the form size have the accurate size instead of having it smaller than the given size (e.g. 500 x 500)?

Here is a video that I’ve made to give you guys a clear picture of my problem.

https://youtu.be/RwN2ZpdPMus

Comment: Are you just trying to create a panel that fills completely the form client surface? Even if you resize the form?

Comment: You forgot about the form borders and caption.  How large the form will exactly be is unpredictable, depends on user preferences.  Something that Winforms deals with by never actually saving the Size, only the ClientSize, so the content always fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form size refers to the outer edge. The form has a resize border all around it plus a title bar where you cannot place controls. The remaining part inside is the `ClientRectangle`. You can get its size through

```
frm.ClientRectangle.Size

' or inside the form itself

ClientRectangle.Size
```

If you set your panels `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Fill`, it will automatically fill up the whole available space. You can do so in the designer in the properties window through a graphical input or in code. The `Size` property, in this case, is irrelevant.

If you add serveral docked controls, the sequence matters. The fist ones will occupy the outer edges, if docked to some edge.

Comment: `ClientSize` does the job too.

Comment: Yes, you can set `panel.Size = ClientSize;` and `panel.Location = new Point(0, 0)`, but setting the `Dock` property is very handy, as it does this automatically and you can change the form size later, without having to care about your panel size.

Comment: Thank you sir, this finally cleared my misconception of thinking that the form size is only the client area of the form. :)